# +1 click is not working in Android integration with Google+

Tags: android, api, google-plus, rate

I followed [this link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend) to use the +1 button in my Android application to +1 a link or a website, but unfortunately it didn't work as expected and it didn't respond when I click on it. I tried to use the following:

```
   mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new OnPlusOneClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPlusOneClick(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivityForResult(arg0, 0);
        }
    });
```

But also no response. As an example I tried to use the following line of code:

```
        mPlusOneButton.initialize(plusClient, "http://www.googleplustoday.net", PLUS_ONE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And there is no effect on my Google plus profile at the +1 tab.

Who can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to be connected to Google Plus:

```
mPlusOneButton.setOnPlusOneClickListener(new OnPlusOneClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPlusOneClick(Intent intent) {
        if(!plusClient.isConnected()) {
            plusClient.connect();
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem. I tried the above one and it worked. But now its showing temporary error please try again later for a long time. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you initialize your `mPlusOneButton` prior to handling clicks such as in the `onResume` method. When I tested by not initializing before the click then I could get it to fail.

In the `androidsdk/extras/google/google_play_services/samples/plus/src/com/google/android/gms/samples/plus/PlusOneActivity.java` contains a skeleton activity for getting the PlusOne button working.

If you can post your full activity code and any applicable errors from logcat that would help further identify the issue.